# Spring referer is null in login and won't redirect

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a Spring-boot app that use security. What I want is to redirect to the original URL requested. I needed to implement a custom SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler so I have this code:

```
public class MySavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

public MySavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
    setUseReferer(true);
}

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) {

// do my stuff

            logger.info(getTargetUrlParameter()); // this is = '/'
            //logger.info(getDefaultTargetUrl()); // this is null
            redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/");
}
}
```

The problem is that after login is never redirecting to the referer. I had to add the **redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/");** part.

In the LoginController, "Referer" in the header is always null when is redirected from spring security. If I put in the url "xxxx/login" the value is set. Not very useful:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/login"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView login(HttpServletRequest request) {       

    String referer = request.getHeader("Referer");
    modelAndView.addObject ("referer", referer); // this is NULL
    //
    modelAndView.setViewName("login");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

This is my security config:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/").authenticated()               
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logged-out")
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied")
```

Comment: Referrer (or Referer as in the spec) is often times null.  User's can set their browsers to never send a referrer.  Another example is when redirecting from https to http the browser is suppose to remove the referrer.  Are you trying to redirect to somewhere specific in your application or are you trying to redirect the user to another domain?  If it is local, [there are ways of redirecting the user to the originally requested page](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-redirect-login).

Comment: Im trying to redirect inside the same site. Just that is session protected that why is redirected to the login page.

Comment: If the requests are only internal, I would recommend using the session based redirects referenced here:  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-redirect-login  From reading the referenced page.  You might be able to remove these two lines of code:  `.failureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler)` and `.successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)` and Everything should just work.  Because 'For form login, SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler is used as the default AuthenticationSuccessHandler.'  Which, is nice.